# Opening up a PowerPoint file using Interop hangs on one users computer

Tags: c#, office-interop, freeze, powerpoint-interop

I'm at a little loss on this one.

I have a C# application that creates PowerPoint presentations from a template file. This application works for all but one user.

On this users computer the application used to run fine but now hangs when trying to open up the PowerPoint file.
The progress bar displays "Importing Template" so I know it's between `ReportProgress("Importing Template");` and `ReportProgress("Expanding Template");`

```
using ppt = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

private bool ExpandTemplateAndSave(string FileName)
{
   bool status = true;

   string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Resources\\pptTemplate.pptx";


   //Back up file is hard coded on server
   if (!File.Exists(path))
   {
      path = @"[Valid Server Path]\Test Build\pptTemplate.pptx";
   }

   ReportProgress("Importing Template");

   ppt.Application app = new ppt.Application();

   ppt.Presentation pres = app.Presentations.Open(path, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

   ReportProgress("Expanding Template");
}
```

What could be causing this to hang?

Comment: The Interop is dependent on the version of Microsoft Office.

Comment: I've updated the post. The user states that the application used to run back a few weeks ago (no development was done in the time frame). Because of this I don't think it would be an Office versioning issue.

Comment: This sound like the version of office was updated recently.  Probably the user Office was updated to 365.

Comment: Thank you, I will ask the user.

Comment: The user has said that their version of Office has not been updated.

Comment: Are they using same version of Office that you are using.  Make sure the version of the Interop is matching the version of office..

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a local file path to the [Presentations.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Presentations.Open) method which opens the specified presentation. Most Office applications can deal with a local file path only, so it seems PowerPoint can have the same limitation.

Another possible pitfall is network access. Firewalls and antivirus software may block applications from accessing remote endpoints.